# Dynamic Excel vba to make selection of dates in slicer

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, selection, slicers

I would like to write a code where the scope of dates is set between startdate (today +1) and enddate(today + 21)

after trying to record scoping the slicer it created the following code(see below)

Maybe there is an solution to refer to 2 cells to scope the startdate and enddate.

so everytime I run this code it gets updated en refreshed for the upcoming 3 weeks.

```
    Sub SLICER()
'
' SLICER Macro
'

'
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Pickdatum")
        .SlicerItems("7-6-2022").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("2-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("9-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("13-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("14-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("15-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("16-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("17-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("20-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("21-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("22-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("23-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("24-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("27-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("28-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("30-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("13-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("14-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("19-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("20-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("21-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("25-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("26-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("28-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("29-7-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("17-8-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("7-9-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("9-9-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("20-9-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("30-12-2022").Selected = False
        SlicerItems("3-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("5-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("6-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("7-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("13-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("14-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("17-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("18-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("19-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("20-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("21-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("24-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("25-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("26-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("27-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("28-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("31-1-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("2-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("7-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("9-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("14-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("15-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("16-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("17-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("18-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("21-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("22-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("23-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("24-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("25-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("28-2-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("2-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("3-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("7-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("9-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("10-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("14-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("15-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("16-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("17-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("18-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("21-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("22-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("23-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("24-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("25-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("28-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("29-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("30-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("31-3-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("4-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("5-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("6-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("7-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("8-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("11-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("12-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("15-4-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("16-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("17-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("18-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("19-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("20-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("23-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("24-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("25-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("27-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("30-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("31-5-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("1-6-2022").Selected = False
        .SlicerItems("18-6-2022").Selected = False
    End With
   
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Pickdatum").ClearManualFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Pickdatum").TimelineState.SetFilterDateRange SDate, EDate`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am not very trained in writing codes, how do I incorporate your line of code???

Comment: @SiddharthRout, when running your line of code I get an 1004 error

Comment: There are 2 kinds of slicers. `xlslicer` and `xltimeline`. If you use the above code on `xlslicer` then you will get an error. You will have to use an `xltimeline` for your purpose and then the above code will work

Comment: Beacuse of you, I came across another unanswered question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752138/why-would-changing-the-start-and-end-date-of-a-slicercache-timelinestate-setfilt Hope the screenshot and the code helps?

Comment: @SiddharthRout still the code written in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752138/why-would-changing-the-start-and-end-date-of-a-slicercache-timelinestate-setfilt gives me the error 1004 hit on the line  `SlcrCache.TimelineState.SetFilterDateRange sDate, eDate `

Comment: Did you change the slicer to timeline as shown on the screenshot?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, yes I did, I have  uploaded the worksheet with code on https://easyupload.io/lvudpt maybe thats easier for you to look at it. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should always avoid using index number because you will never know which slicer is it referring to. The slicer that you want to work with is `ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("OorspronkelijkeTijdlijn_datum").TimelineState.SetFilterDateRange sDate, Fdate`

Comment: @SiddharthRout It Works thanks, but it's not possible with a slicer instead of timeline?

Comment: Not an easy way that I am aware of. You will have to recreate the Pivot and the slicer with the necessary time lines.